# How can a Gaussian process be almost surely bounded?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

I came across the [Borell-TIS Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borell%E2%80%93TIS_inequality#cite_note-RFG-1) which presents a result for a Gaussian process. In it, the condition is that let $f_t$ be a centered Gaussian process for $t \in T$ where $T$ is a topological space. It is then assumed that the Gaussian process is almost surely bounded on $T$, i.e. $\sup_{t \in T} |f_t|$ is almost surely finite.

I am confused by this requirement. How can a Gaussian process be almost surely bounded? I mean, fix $t_0 \in T$. Then $f_{t_0}$ is a Gaussian random variable by definition of a Gaussian process. We know that the measure for which $|f_{t_0}| > \tau$ where $\tau $ is the threshold is never zero. So how can this be true for the process?

Is this rather obvious...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition is $$P(\sup_{t \in T} |f_t| < \infty) = 1,$$
but you seem to be thinking about a different condition
$$\text{there exists $M$ such that }P(\sup_{t \in T} |f_t| \le M) = 1.$$

Comment: In other words, $M$ is allowed to depend on the outcome $\omega$ in the sample space.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that I was reading it incorrectly.